# Como manter aplicação MVC rodando no IIS express (no Visual Studio) após parar o debug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Estou fazendo um projeto em ASP.Net MVC. Na máquina da empresa eu rodo o projeto uma vez (F5), paro o debug e continuo acessando as páginas da aplicação normalmente.

Na minha máquina pessoal se eu paro o debug aparece a página falando que não é possível acessar o site porque não foi encontrado, ou seja, se eu quero navegar na aplicação, sempre tem que estar debuggando.

**Imagino que exista uma configuração no Visual Studio para não interromper a aplicação ao parar o debug, qual seria?**

Utilizo Visual Studio 2015 em ambas as máquinas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível manter o IIS Express executando a sua aplicação mesmo depois de parar o debug, para isso é necessário desativar a opção *Edit and continue* no Visual Studio.

Passo a passo: No menu superior clique em **ferramentas (tools) > opções (options) > debugging**, role até o final e desmarque a caixa de seleção *Enable edit and continue*.